# jquery tooltip doesn't display content on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am trying to display `table` as a `tooltip` content.

However the table doesn't seem to show.

Here's the HTML:

```
<td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip1" class="red-tooltip" title="">5 Users</a>
</td>
```

The table:

```
<table id="tooltipContent" border="4" bordercolor="black" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="15px" style="width: 800px; display: none;">
     <tr><td>ravi_shrestha(r_sth@gmail.com)</td></tr>
     <tr><td>ravi_shrestha(r_sth@gmail.com)</td></tr>
     <tr><td>ravi_shrestha(r_sth@gmail.com)</td></tr>
</table>
```

Tooltip initialization:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip1"]').tooltip({
         content: $('#tooltipContent').html()
    });                
 },
```

Putting something in `title` attribute itself is working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a callback function, properly add the js and css dependencies

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip1"]').tooltip({
         content: function() { return $('#tooltipContent').html();}
});
```

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip1"]').tooltip({
  content: function() {
    return $('#tooltipContent').html();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<td>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip1" class="red-tooltip" title="">5 Users</a>
</td>

<table id="tooltipContent" border="4" bordercolor="black" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="15px" style="width: 800px; display: none;">
  <tr>
    <td>ravi_shrestha(r_sth@gmail.com)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ravi_shrestha(r_sth@gmail.com)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ravi_shrestha(r_sth@gmail.com)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: in the snippet is working, have you got any console errors?

Comment: no.. console is empty.. it is working in the snippet though.. surprising..

Comment: that means the code is ether not called or you have some conflict in your code

Comment: Do we have to inject `jquery-ui.css` and `jquery-ui.js` too?

Comment: from what i can see yes